# Safely block multiprocessing.Queue until element is received by another process

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I want to pass messages of various types between two different processes in both directions using the `multiprocessing` package. My class looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np

class MessagePasser:
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue(maxsize=1)
        self.event = multiprocessing.Event()
    
    def send_message(self, message: np.ndarray|int) -> None:
        self.queue.put(message)
        # block until message has been received (event set by the receiver)
        self.event.wait()
        self.event.clear()

    def receive_message(self) -> np.ndarray|int:
        # block until message has been sent
        while self.queue.empty():
            pass
        message = self.queue.get()
        # now it should be safe for the sender to exit `send_message`
        self.event.set()
        return message
```

So the idea is to allow only a single object in the `multiprocessing.Queue` and use `multiprocessing.Event` to block the sender's access to the queue by "capturing" it in the `send_message`-method until the receiver got the message. This way, or so I thought, messages should be transmitted safely if for each call to `send_message` by one process there is a call to `receive_message` by another process. However, this does not work using the following main code:

```
def alices_job(message_passer: MessagePasser):
    for i in range(1000):
        array = np.random.rand(10)
        integer = 1
        message_passer.send_message(array)
        message_passer.send_message(integer)
        modified_array = message_passer.receive_message()
        modified_array.sum()

def bobs_job(message_passer: MessagePasser):
    for i in range(1000):
        array = message_passer.receive_message().astype(float)
        integer = message_passer.receive_message()
        array *= int(integer)
        message_passer.send_message(array)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    message_passer = MessagePasser()
    alices_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=alices_job, args=(message_passer,))
    bobs_process = multiprocessing.Process(target=bobs_job, args=(message_passer,))
    alices_process.start()
    bobs_process.start()
    alices_process.join()
    bobs_process.join()
```

Obviously, each call to `send_message` in `alices_job` corresponds to a call to `receive_message` in `bobs_job`. But my attempt of blocking does not seem to work. In some random iteration of the loop the whole program either hangs or it gives me the error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

in the last line of `alices_job` indicating that the sending process picked up its own message. I also tried `multiprocessing.connections.PipeConnections`, which seem to be faster, but cause the same problems (unless I use two pipes, which is not practical for my application as the assignment of connectors to processes could not take place during construction of `MessagePasser`).

My goal is not to realize a server-client model but to enable bidirectional message passing between two parties, very similar to the blocking send and receive functions in MPI, but with shared memory and without the need to specify the sender/receiver since only two processes are present. If somehow possible, I would like to accomplish that with only slight modifications and no additional packages like `threading` or `concurrent.futures`, using only `multiprocessing`, which is already used for other parts of my application. Many thanks in advance

Comment: The whole point of a queue is you can have things waiting in line. You don't want to block them from getting in line at all. All you've done with the event is create a deadlock that provides no benefit. Let multiprocessing.Queue handle the messages because that is its job. Also why is the sender receiving messages? Why is the receiver sending messages?

Comment: It's unclear. See [ask]. It's an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Describe the protocol of the communication between processes. I guess you want a client and server model, where a client sends a request and receives a response from the server. In that case, the ```multiprocessing``` module provides the RPC(remote procedure call). See [Customized managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) and [Using a remote manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager).

Comment: @KennyOstrom I do want to block them. That's why I asked the question. If you are referring to the limitation to only one element in the queue you are probably right that I don't need that, but that does not change my problem that the sending process picks up its own message. The names `senders_job` and `receivers_job` originate from the application I want to use this for, where the sender needs a confirmation from the receiver. You can replace them by `alices_job` and `bobs_job`, `aladdins_job` and `jasmines_job` or whatever if it bothers you that the sender's job includes receiving messages.

Comment: @relent95 And what point in "How to ask" do you mean exactly? I chose the title to be a short summary of my problem / the desired solution, posted my entire current "solution", and described precisely what my problem is and where it happens. My wish to avoid additional packages was accompanied by the word "preferably" if that is what bothers you. And in case you haven't noticed: Pretty much every question here is an XY problem because questions like "I want to do Y, tell me how" would be answered, if at all, with references to "How to ask" and a lot of downvotes.

Comment: I mean you didn't explicitly describe your desired protocol. So I had to guess like "you want a client and server model ...". Still I'm not sure what you want. For mentioning the XY problem, I don't mean you don't need to provide what you tried, but you need to provide your goal. If you want a client and server model I mentioned before, your current approach using a Queue is very wrong, as Kenny already commented.

Comment: @relent95 Okay, I edited my question to (hopefully) clarify what I want.

Comment: I don't recommend implementing a protocol that deviates from standard patterns such as the client-server, producer-consumer, etc. Anyway, you can use the ```multiprocessing.Pipe```. See [Exchanging objects between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: Send a message, wait for the response? What you're describing is just client-server. Yes, you can do that with queues, but you'll need different ones for each direction. Right now you just have one queue, so a worker is more likely to post a message then immediately grab its own message off the queue (instead of a response). A pipe would be better as relent95 said above.

Comment: I don't think the situation will change if we have to use a two-way pipe. The problem would be much simpler if we could use two pipes or queues, could you explain why this is not possible?

Comment: `self.queue.empty()` is *not* reliable. And why would you want to do a "busy" wait instead of just calling `message = self.queue.get()` without the non-productive preceding `while` loop?

Comment: Do you still need an answer? I might have to change it a bit to what I think you want.